# Ironpython, Silverlight, ASP.NET MVC for production site

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, ironpython

I am looking to build a new website which will require a sql server backend and silverlight front end.  I would also like to take advantage of the MVC framework.  I currently code in C#, but am looking to learn a new type of language on this project.  I've been reading up on F#, IronRuby and IronPython.  IronPython seems to catch my eye the most, although I'm not completely closed to IronRuby.  F# as I understand it is still more of a research language so I'm a bit wary of writing production code using it - IronPython and IronRuby have also pre-existed for several years whereas F# is completely new.  My reasons for picking one of these three languages are that they are all functional and run on the DLR.

A few questions:

1) Will IronPython work well with Silverlight and MVC?  If you have used IronPython in this combination I am very interested in hearing your thoughts.

2) How well does IronPython integrate into Visual Studio? I'm not completely against using some other editor... maybe Notepad++ or whatever, but since VS is really nice I would like to use it if i can.

3) How well does IronPython work with existing ASP.NET (and silverlight maybe?) server controls?  I've run through some tutorials on wiring up winforms control events with IronPython - is it the same for ASP.NET controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a partial answer to question 1, there was this question asked on StackOverflow:

[IronPython on ASP.NET MVC (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441838/ironpython-on-asp-net-mvc)

Scott Hanselman had some useful links to using IronPython in a bunch of different scenarios from last year (so it may be a bit out of date):

[IronPython and the DLR march on (Scott Hanselman)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IronPythonAndTheDLRMarchOn.aspx)

In answer to question 2, you can download both integrated and isolated mode installers for Visual Studio 2008 from here:

[IronPython Studio 1.0 (CodePlex)](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8934)

I've been using it on and off for a while and it seems to work just fine.

And finally, in answer to question 3, you might want to take a look at this series of articles on:

[Beginning IronPython (ASP.NET IronPython Resource)](http://www.ironpythonresource.com/post/2008/08/03/Beginning-IronPython-Creating-a-basic-ASPNET-Form-(Part-1).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I love all of these languages but I just wanted to give some deserved love to F#. F# 1.0 [was released](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2005/01/05/346857.aspx) to the public on or around January 5, 2005. IronPython 1.0, the oldest of the DLR languages, [was released](http://blogs.msdn.com/hugunin/archive/2006/09/05/741605.aspx) on September 5, 2006. IronRuby 0.5 [was released](http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2009/05/ironruby-05-released.html) just mere weeks ago.

Additionally, F# will be included in Visual Studio 2010 whereas IronPython and IronRuby require extra steps to integrate them with Visual Studio.

That said, ASP.NET and MVC support for F# is pretty much non-existent whereas IronPython and IronRuby have various efforts underway already. There is [Dynamic Language support for ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/DynamicLanguages/), [Dynamic Language support for Silverlight](http://github.com/jschementi/agdlr/tree/master) and even the [IronRuby MVC project](http://github.com/jschementi/ironrubymvc/tree/master). Whether or not any of these are suitable for a production project is up to you and your comfort level with the frameworks.

Matthew Podwysocki has an [excellent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/10/06/asp-net-mvc-with-nhaml-f-edition.aspx) on using F# with the MVC framework.

Comment: I actually like the idea of using F#, but my concern is the community support. There seems to be more buzz around IronPython??  maybe because of it's pre-existance as CPython..  Or maybe I'm not looking in the right corners on the web for my F# news...

Comment: F# has a very supportive community on hubFS http://cs.hubfs.net and here on StackOverflow as well. It's more likely than not that your questions will even get answers directly from the F# team.

Comment: so what, in your opinion, would be the advantages of F# over IronPython?

Comment: For web application development? I'm not sure that there are any advantages over IronPython right now. As much as I love F# as a general purpose language, I think dynamic languages are actually better suited for web development.