# Using python code in ASP.NET Web forms app

Tags: .net, asp.net, python, ironpython

I would like to use some code written in python (it uses built in modules) in a regular ASP.NET/C# web application. I am a newbie in python and have heard of IronPython and how ASP.NET now allows us to create IronPython apps.

Any thoughts on which way I should proceed? The python code is the on [here](http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links:

- http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20Language%20Support&ProjectName=aspnet
- [IronPython on ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441838/ironpython-on-asp-net-mvc)

If the above approaches do not suit the problem, it is quite simple to embed the IronPython engine from C#. See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/embedding.shtml .

Comment: IronPython is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Sorry for being dense. Are you saying I should convert the python code to Iron Python project and embed it into my ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 1):

You can fill ASP.NET web forms from python or any other programming language. The format of this message should be simply `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - urlencoding to POST data is done by default by requests package, so you should not add additional urlencode yourself.

To be successful with ASP.NET web forms automation you should know that as always you have to handle cookies properly (using `requests` session will be enough), but also send back hidden input fields called `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`. You can can find additional information [here](https://funinit.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/asp-net-web-form-as-api/) and check example of working code [here](https://github.com/cinek810/Specops-password-unlocker/blob/master/AccountUnlock.py).